# Using multiple SSH keys in Docker with ssh-agent

Tags: git, docker, go, ssh

I have a Go module that uses two private dependencies (two private repositories on GitHub). I'm wanting to use deploy keys to authenticate as I believe this is the best way. I'm following [this guide](https://gist.github.com/jrapoport/d12f60029eef017354d0ec982b918258).

I have added the key to ssh-agent with `ssh-add ~/.ssh/akamai`, and when I run `ssh-add -l` I can see the key.

If I have my Dockerfile like this, it works when running with `docker build --ssh default .`:

```
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN touch ~/.ssh/config

RUN --mount=type=ssh git clone git@github.com:SolarSystems-Software/akamai
```

The problem is when I add this command to modify `~/.ssh/config` to add a custom host pointing to the specific private key;

```
RUN echo "\nHost akamai-repo\nHostName github.com\nIdentityFile ~/.ssh/akamai\nIdentitiesOnly yes\n" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

I get this error:

```
#12 1.484 no such identity: /root/.ssh/akamai: No such file or directory
#12 1.484 git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I understand that it can't find the private key file, so my question is, how can I add multiple keys with `ssh-add` to use in Docker, and then make a custom config to point to a specific one? This example I've posted is only with one key, but once I get this working I'm going to add the second key.

Comment: It takes a lot more than two keys before you need to specify which one to use from an agent. Just let the client retry all the keys the agent has until it finds the right one. That'll work fine _until_ you have so many keys it outnumbers the number of retries the server allows, but that number is always much more than two.

Comment: Anyhow -- setting up an SSH agent with your keys should happen _on your host_ where you're running Docker; it's not something you put in your Dockerfile or do inside the container; `RUN --mount=type=ssh` is responsible for plumbing a socket to that agent through and setting up `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`; things are generally automatic.

Comment: If you _are_ going to use an IdentityFile directive, the filename it includes should have the public key -- if you use `ssh-add -L` to list all the public keys your agent has private keys for, the public key you choose needs to be in that list. Until `ssh-add -L` lists public keys, you're not ready to use IdentityFile.

Comment: ...but as for the "how do I add keys to my agent _in Docker_?" -- you _don't_ do that in Docker. You do that _before you start_ Docker.

Comment: (I shouldn't have said "always" much more than two -- much more than two unless someone is deliberately forcing a client to pick the right key in the first attempt, would be more accurate; but there's little incentive for a server to be set up that way)

Comment: ...but bottom line, this isn't really a Docker question, or a programming question; you need to set up and populate the SSH agent the same way you'd do it if you weren't using Docker at all. (BTW, using hardware keystores is a really great motivating use case for accessing SSH keys _exclusively_ through an agent; if you're doing it right, your general-purpose CPU, and thus any malware it runs, has no direct access to the key material, and so can't copy or leak it).